# Inequality by inspection

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

I have the following inequality. For $x\geq0$
$$|\sqrt{x}-3|\leq|\frac{x}{3}-3|$$
This holds but is there an obvious way of seeing this except for solving for $x$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set $x=9y^2$ to find $$3|y-1|\le3|y^2-1|\iff3|y-1|(|y+1|-1)\ge0$$ which is obvious

Comment: How did you get $1+|y+1|$? I'm getting:
\begin{align}
3|y-1| \leq 3|y^2-1| &\iff 3(|(y+1)(y-1)| - |y-1|) \geq 0 \\
&\iff 3|y-1|(|y+1|-1) \geq 0
\end{align}

Comment: @WB-man, Thanks for your observation

Comment: You're welcome. Although I think it might be good to append "for $y \geq 0$" after saying "Set $x = 9y^2$" because otherwise the expression $(|y+1|-1)$ could be negative if, say, $y = -1$. This was my original concern when I wrote the first comment.